# How to use same data connection from another projects in the same solution in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have many projects under 1 solution, one of the project has data connection and i want to use that data connection in my newly created project, Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Thanks
Preet

Comment: By data connection,  do you mean something like a connectionString from an app.config/web.config?

Comment: what are those two project types?

Comment: Take the data from the project code to the config.

Comment: Please provide some more details about your problem.